# Check if apex is being run in Rest Resource

Tags: apex, apexrest, rest-service, restresource

Is there a way to check if being run in RestResource Context? I have a script that posts messages to an endpoint but we can end up in an infinite loop scenario as they are now posting their comments to us. How can I check for this flag or flag this during runtime?

Ideally something like:

```
Test.isRunningTest()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check if you're in a REST call via:

```
Request.getCurrent().getQuiddity() == Quiddity.REST
```

You can read more about the [Request](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Request.htm) object, as well as the possible values for [Quiddity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_enum_System_Quiddity.htm).